# How to start/stop recording automatically when there is someone starts talking?

Tags: linux, audio, recording

I want to start recording when someone starts talking, and stop recording when it becomes silent.

I guess if there is stream audio processing tool like `ImageMagick`, so I can strip away blank sections like this:

```
$ rec -t wav - | wavefilter -strip-blank=3sec | lame - >record1.mp3
```

**EDIT**

This question is resolved by using:

```
$ rec -t wav - silence 1 0.1 3% -1 1.0 3% | lame - >record1.mp3
```

Comment: I have developed a software that does exactly this , I am willing to provide it with certain cost if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `silence` predicate of [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) can strip silence from the middle of an audio file.

Comment: Thank you. BTW, I found this one, http://digitalcardboard.com/blog/2009/08/25/the-sox-of-silence/